# apply() function in Scala giving a compile error?

Tags: arrays, scala, compilation

Hey I have the following piece of code:

```
var z:Array[String] = new Array[String](4);
z(0) = "Dave"; 
z(1) = "Joe";
z(2) = "Jim";
z.apply(3) = "Roger";
```

The last line here is giving a compile time error saying - "missing arguments for method apply in class Array; follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function"

This does not make sense to me, as I have read that when you apply parentheses surrounding one more values to a variable, Scala will transform the code into an invocation of a method named apply on that variable.
So if the following line:

```
z(2) = "Jim";
```

gets converted to

```
z.apply(2) = "Jim";
```

Then why does the line

```
z.apply(3) = "Roger";
```

give me a compile time error?

I am new with Scala so any help would be great thanks!

Comment: Interesting question, since the `Array#apply` [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array) state: `Indices start at 0; xs.apply(0) is the first element of array xs. Note the indexing syntax xs(i) is a shorthand for xs.apply(i).`

Comment: What you are doing gets de-sugared to `update`, not `apply`. The docs for `update` are similar: `Indices start at 0; xs.update(i, x) replaces the ith element in the array. Note the syntax xs(i) = x is a shorthand for xs.update(i, x).`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This call:

```
z(2) = "Jim";
```

Gets translated to

```
z.update(2, "Jim")
```

`apply` doesn't work when you try to assign the value.

**Update**

You can check it by yourself. Run in the console: `scala -print`, and type `val ar = Array(1, 2, 3)`

Then, when you type next line `ar(2) = 5`, it will show you the generated code. It's a bit complicated (the interpreter adds a lot of stuff for it's own purpose), but you will be able to find this (or similar) line:

```
    $line3.iw.ar().update(2, 5);
```

Comment: How can you show that de-sugaring - only by looking at the `bytecode`?

Comment: @KevinMeredith Please see my update. It's about scala code rather than bytecode - we do not have to go so deep to see how it is translated

Answer (score 2):

The [Scala Language Specification - Section 6.15](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#assignments) covers this thoroughly:

> An assignment `f(args) = e` with a function application to the left of the `=` operator is interpreted as `f.update(args, e)`, i.e. the invocation of an `update` function defined by `f`.

So in other words, the compiler changes assignment syntax on the mutable array `z` from

`z(i) = "Name"` to `z.update(i, "Name")`

`z.apply(3) = "Roger"` isn't covered by this specific rule, so it doesn't work.

---

Assignment syntaxes from the spec include:

```
assignment      expansion

x.f = e         x.f_=(e)
x.f() = e       x.f.update(e)
x.f(i) = e      x.f.update(i, e)
x.f(i, j) = e   x.f.update(i, j, e)
```